# Cancel UIRefreshControl when dragged up

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uirefreshcontrol

when refreshing is taking place, (actionwheel is spinning after pull down), 
I want to be able to cancel refreshing - much like Facebook app.

pull down to refresh and while not done yet, if i pull up so that the spinner is outside my view, i stop/cancel the refresh.

i've tried to check the scrollViewDidScroll so check against the first visible row, but the action isn't as smooth.

any better idea on how to implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

actually, just figured it out. hope it helps some :)

when starting refresh, set some kind of flag (here would be 'refreshing'), 
and simply check 1. refreshing state  2. detect whether contentOffset is zeroed out.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    //NSLog(@"%f",[self.tableView contentOffset].y);
    if(refreshing){
        if([self.tableView contentOffset].y >= 0){
            refreshing = NO;
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to your solution, you can use the internal flag to check and see if it is currently refreezing

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{{
if (self.refreshControl.refreshing){
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
}
```